# How to handle GET & POST in Flask and Angular 8

Tags: python-3.x, flask, angular8

I am trying to build an app with `angular 8` and `Flask`. In the Login form, I am sending the `username` and `password` to the `flask server` using `post`.

```
@app.route("/Login",methods=['GET','POST'])
def Login():
    session.pop('user',None)
    if request.method=='POST':
        data=request.get_json()
        flag=dbobject.validate(data['email'],data['password'],cursor)
        if flag==1:
            return jsonify({"response":'Login Successful'})
        if flag==2:
            return jsonify({"response":'Wrong password'})
        if flag==3:
            return jsonify({"response":'You have not registered'})
    return jsonify({'response': 'OK'})
```

I am trying to get the response after the the validation using

```
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/Login').subscribe(data => {
const responseData = data as JSON;
```

but I am getting the response `{'response': 'OK'}`

Is there a way i can take the response of the login validation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
@app.route("/Login",methods=['GET','POST'])
def Login():
    session.pop('user',None)
    if request.method=='POST':
        data=request.get_json()
        flag=dbobject.validate(data['email'],data['password'],cursor)
        if flag==1:
            response = 'Login Successful'
        if flag==2:
            response = 'Wrong password'
        if flag==3:
            response = 'You have not registered'
    return jsonify({'response': 'OK', 'reponse_msg':response})
```

You will get the response of the login validation message in the response_msg variable in the frontend.

Comment: Hi..Actually, i figured it out. The get request also contains the response given by the server. I was also storing that into the variable responseData. But i called another method to get the response which used get method instead. Obviously it didn't work. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with the response received by POST request (without using GET request).

On Angular:

```
this.http.post('your_url', JSON.stringify('data_to_be_sent')).subscribe((response)=>{
   let result=response["response"];
   console.log(result);
});
```

On Server side:

```
@app.route("/Login",methods=['POST'])
def Login():
    msg=''
    data=request.get_json()
    flag=dbobject.validate(data['email'],data['password'],cursor)
    if flag==1:
        msg='Login Succesfull'
    if flag==2:
        msg='Incorrect Password'
    if flag==3:
        msg='You have not registered'
    return jsonify({'response': msg})
```